# Regarding sum of squares two ways how are they connected

Tags: anova, terminology, sums-of-squares

$$
\sum(X^2) - \frac{(\sum X)^2}{n} = \sum(X^2) - m\sum X
$$
This was nicely derived in [Sum of squares two ways, how are they connected?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/sum-of-squares-two-ways-how-are-they-connected)

But why is the second term called the "correction term for the mean"?  This is lost on me. What is needing correction and why?

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you asking how to get from the left hand side of the equation to the right hand side algebraically? Are you asking about the meaning of the quoted phrase? If so, can you connect it more clearly to the equation? Linking to the thread where you found this would help a lot.

Comment: The OP may be referring to this thread: [Sum of squares two ways, how are they connected?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/)

Answer (score 2):

The first term is just the sum of of squared *observations*; the second term corrects it to give the sum of squared *deviations from the sample mean*.